# How do I fill a list view using a data table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, listview

I already have the datatable. I just need to fill it in the list view. The problem is that I'm running into this error:

'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayMember' and no extension method 'DisplayMember' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I thought the list view had a "DisplayMember" property? This is ASP .NET 4.0, by the way.

```
namespace Eagle_Replication_Manager
{
    public partial class wfrmMain : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //on page load, I want to get a database table and populate this list view: 
            lvItems.DataSource = GetSourceDBs();

            //This does not work, error here:
            lvItems.DisplayMember = "Description";
        }

        private DataTable GetSourceDBs()
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(AppVars.connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Description] FROM [Warehouse].[dbo].[Items]", conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            da.Fill(dt);
                            return dt;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lvItems.DataSource = GetSourceDBs();
        lvItems.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: InvalidOperationException was unhandled by the user code. An ItemTemplate must be defined on ListView 'lvItems'. I see I have to set the ItemTemplate but what are the options!?

Comment: The idea is that in your markup you have to define <ItemTemplate> with all your columns, etc. If you don't want to do that, then just use GridView instead as it can automatically generate the table for you without any extra work.

Comment: Ahh, I see. The reason why I'm using a list view is because the user would be selecting an item from it so I can do an action based on his/her selection.

Comment: What kind of action? GridView also supports editing/selecting  functionality and I think you should be able to achieve the same result.

Comment: Selection. Basically whatever the user selects, I need to put that value into a variable. So it's doable with a gridview? if it is, then I'm going to go that route. I hate messing around with HTML/CSS, etc etc. grrrr haha

Answer (score 0):

Public void getdataToList(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(" << put your connection string >>");

```
 try {
   lvItems.Columns.Clear() ;
   lvItems.Items.Clear();

   conn.Open();
   txtSql.Text ="select * from Employee";

   SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
   cmd.CommandText = txtSql.Text;

   SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   for (int i = 0; i< dr.FieldCount; i++) {
     ColumnHeader ch = new ColumnHeader();
     ch.Text=dr.GetName(i);
     lvItems.Columns.Add(ch);
   }

   ListViewItem itmX; 

   while (dr.Read()) {
     itmX=new ListViewItem(); 
     itmX.Text= dr.GetValue(0).ToString();

     for (int i=1 ; i< dr.FieldCount; i++) {
        itmX.SubItems.Add(dr.GetValue(i).ToString());
     }
     lvwResult.Items.Add(itmX);
   }
   dr.Close();
} catch ( System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException  ex) {
   Console.WriteLine("There was an error in executing the SQL." +
           "\nError Message:" + ex.Message, "SQL");
} finally {
   conn.Close();
}
```